# Hide warnings in layout files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-lint

I updated Eclipse and SDK and now in every xml file the TextViews have the warning "Consider making the text value selectable by specifying android:textIsSelectable="true"".

Is it possible to hide the warnings, I hate to have my project with a lot of yellow exclamation marks.

Comment: You can ignore certain lint warnings. Open the "Lint warnings" tab. Click the warning you wish to suppress. Click "Ignore in this project" and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the propeties of your project. Go to Android Lint Preferences. Search for SelectableText  and change the severity to ignore.

You can also do this in Eclipse preferences for all projects.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason for this warning. By just disabling it, you are basically ignoring user interface guidelines of Android and you are not using the full potential of the user interface of your app. Therefore looking at each text view and explicitly setting this attribute to either false or true will increase the quality of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The warning could be a bit clearer though and suggest setting true or false rather than asking me to consider setting the value to true!